# Prove that any family of pairwise disjoint open intervals is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Having trouble solving the following problem:

Prove that any family of pairwise disjoint open intervals is countable.

Any help would be great!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5049/countability-of-disjoint-intervals

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

In every such open (non-trivial) interval there's *at least* one rational, and the union of all these rationals over that family is *at most* $\;\Bbb Q\;$ , and the cardinality of $\;\Bbb Q\; $ is....

Or another (kind of) approach: as before with the rationals: if the family were uncountable, then taking the union of it would yield uncountable rationals...

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for your help.